# Put value in three different arrays every third time

Tags: php, arrays

I have a foreach in which I have three different arrays. I want to put the value - when running the foreach - in the different arrays every third time (look example below for better explanation).

```
Ex: arr = blue, red, green, yellow, brown

arr1 = blue, yellow arr2 = red, brown arr3 = green
```

I have this code (but dont work because the modulus doesn't come down to the last if statement more then the first execution of the if).

```
$count = 0;
foreach($values as $value){
    if($count%2){
        $arrSecond[] = $value[img][url];
    }
    else if($count%3){
        $arrThird[] = $value[img][url];
    }
    else {
        $arrFirst[] = $value[img][url];
    }
    $count++;
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Just as an FYI, modulus is probably one of the most expensive operators.

Comment: use a switch statement and do $count % 3 a single time.

Comment: @OmarJackman Better yet, if count is just to decide which statement to use then simply putting it back to 0 when it reaches 3 and having `if == 2` and `if == 3`, or a switch as you suggest, would suffice. If not, a new variable.

Comment: While most of the other answers have nailed it, the reason your code would fail is that modulus 2, will result in every other value being placed in `$arrSecond` - meaning all the odd indexes.  The even indexes will then be checked against %3, and it'll take anything where the remainder isn't 1 (meaning 2, 4, 8, 10, etc).  Finally, all the leftovers (even and divisible by 3, e.g. 6, 12, 18) will be stuck in `$arrFirst`

Comment: Althought it's not a problem, but I assume you don't realy want to use constants in the following case: `$value[img][url]`. Better use strings for receiving the value of a index: `$value['img']['url']`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be using modulus 3 the whole time only with different offsets:

```
foreach($values as $value){
    $mod = $count%3;
    if($mod == 1){
        $arrSecond[] = $value['img']['url'];
    }
    // elseif, not else if!
    elseif($mod == 2){
        $arrThird[] = $value['img']['url'];
    }
    else {
        $arrFirst[] = $value['img']['url'];
    }
    $count++;
}
```

Comment: a little shorter version of the above:

`$ref = array(&$arrFirst, &$arrSecond, &$arrThird);
$c = 2;
foreach($values as $value) {
    $ref[++$c % 3][] = $value['img']['url'];
}`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks. And thanks everybody else for the answers!

Comment: @cwallenpoole I'm not sure how one is right or wrong?  The documentation page is titled [elseif/else if](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php), suggesting they're equivalent, except for the caveat of when people use colons for their statements, which seems like a small edge case . . .

Comment: @ernie It is the difference between `else{if(/*stuff*/){}}` and `elseif(/*stuff*/){}`

Answer (score 4):

Or you could simply make a single array:

```
$count = 0;
$data = array();
foreach($source as $value) {
   $data[$count % 3][] = $value[img][url];
   $count++;
}
```

That gives you 3 sub arrays with the $value stuff spread out evening within them.

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is the following:

```
$count = 0;
foreach($values as $value){
    switch($count){
        case 0:
            $arrFirst[] = $value[img][url];
            $count = 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            $arrSecond[] = $value[img][url];
            $count = 2;
            break;
        case 2:
            $arrThird[] = $value[img][url];
            $count = 0;
            break;
    }
}
```

This is basically a 3 state state machine which should be more efficient than using modulus for a large number of images.